# What is new at The Surge's new game plus?

Tags: the-surge

The [wiki](http://thesurge.wiki.fextralife.com/New+Game+Plus) says that at ng+ you get:

1. New equipment tiers.
2. New enemies placement.
3. Enemies will hit harder and will have more armor.
4. "Extra secrets that only the keenest-eyed players will spot!"

**What are these ng+ secrets exactly?**
And **are there other changes, which were not mentioned?** For example, the power conduit at the first area has changed power requirement from 55 to 80, but wiki hasn't mentioned change in power requirements.

Comment: Look, look with your keen eyes!

Answer (score 2):

I have just started a New Game + playthrough, and I have noticed the following changes so far:

- Enemy Toughness. Standard enemies have been upgraded, like the attack drones and Lynx enemies. There are also interspersed higher level enemies, capable of one hitting you to your death, or taking all of your stamina away when blocking. They have different looking armor and weapons, though in the first area, only seem to drop Lynx RIG parts. (Correction: These enemies can sometimes hold Black Cerberus armor parts, and a full set is needed for a trophy.)
- Gear upgrades. Instead of Mark I through IV, you now have VI through IX. Nano Core conduits have also had their levels increased.
- Boss Battles. The PAX Imperator was significantly more difficult in NG+, and the same can likely be said for the later bosses.
- Knowledge. Obviously having played through the game, you've got knowledge of where to go and what to do. I have not yet found any significant secrets, but navigation was much easier for me the second time around.

I'm sure there's more, and I can post as I find it, since I'm cleaning up trophies on the NG+ run.

Answer (score 0):

Also:

- NG+ tiers up to NG+++ allow to acquire more powerful rigs - with more implant slots. According to [Rigs - Wiki](https://thesurge.wiki.fextralife.com/Rigs) the best rig has 34 implant slots in NG+++.
- Weapons dropped from the last boss are only available to use in NG+ - they are [Mimetic Edge](https://thesurge.wiki.fextralife.com/Mimetic+Edge) and [Claws of the Gestalt](https://thesurge.wiki.fextralife.com/Claws+of+the+Gestalt).